Почему постоянно перезагружается index.php?
У меня есть auth.php в нем страница где размещен код который авторизируется с помощью кошелька тон, получает данные телеграмм и отправляет пост запрос на auth_post.php с помощью скрипта main.js а сам auth_post.php в случае если пользователь существует то добавляет сессию и перенаправляет на index.php точно так же если пользователя не существует, добавляет его в бд создает сессию и перенаправляет на index.php
auth.php
    <?php
session_start(); // Инициализация сессии

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
header('Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT'); // Истёкший заголовок
header('Pragma: no-cache'); // Для старых браузеров


require_once 'config.php'; // Подключение к базе данных
header('Content-Type: application/json'); // Заголовок ответа

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $data = json_decode($inputJSON, true);

    if (json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE && isset($data['user'])) {
        $user = $data['user'];
        $referrer_id = $data['referrer_id'] ?? null;
        $ref_url = $data['ref_url'] ?? null;
        $auth_date = $data['auth_date'] ?? null;
        $hash = $data['hash'] ?? null;
        $wallet_address = $data['wallet_address'] ?? null;

        try {
            // Проверяем, существует ли пользователь
            $stmt_check_user = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = ?");
            $stmt_check_user->execute([$user['id']]);
            $existing_user = $stmt_check_user->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            if ($existing_user) {
                // Пользователь существует - авторизация
                $_SESSION['user'] = [
                    'id' => $existing_user['user_id'],
                    'language_code' => $existing_user['language_code'],
                    'wallet_address' => $existing_user['wallet_address']
                ];

                // Перенаправляем на index.php
                header('Location: ./index.php');
                exit();
            } else {
                // Пользователя нет - регистрация
                $pdo->beginTransaction();

                $stmt_insert_user = $pdo->prepare("
                    INSERT INTO users (user_id, first_name, last_name, username, language_code, ref_url, auth_date, hash, wallet_address)
                    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
                ");
                $stmt_insert_user->execute([
                    $user['id'],
                    $user['first_name'],
                    $user['last_name'],
                    $user['username'],
                    $user['language_code'],
                    $ref_url,
                    $auth_date,
                    $hash,
                    $wallet_address
                ]);

                if ($referrer_id) {
                    $stmt_insert_referral = $pdo->prepare("
                        INSERT INTO referral (referrer_id, user_id)
                        VALUES (?, ?)
                    ");
                    $stmt_insert_referral->execute([$referrer_id, $user['id']]);
                }

                $pdo->commit();

                // Создаём сессию для нового пользователя
                $_SESSION['user'] = [
                    'id' => $user['id'],
                    'language_code' => $user['language_code'],
                    'wallet_address' => $wallet_address
                ];

                // Перенаправляем на index.php
                header('Location: ./index.php');
                exit();
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $pdo->rollBack();
            http_response_code(500);
            echo json_encode(['success' => false, 'message' => $e->getMessage()]);
        }
    } else {
        // Неверные данные
        http_response_code(400);
        echo json_encode(['success' => false, 'message' => 'Invalid JSON data']);
    }
} else {
    // Неверный метод запроса
    http_response_code(405);
    echo json_encode(['success' => false, 'message' => 'Method not allowed']);
}

?>

index.php
    <?php
session_start(); // Инициализация сессии

// Подключаем конфигурацию базы данных
require_once 'config.php';

header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate');


// Проверяем, существует ли сессия пользователя
if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    $userId = $_SESSION['user']['id'];
    $walletAddress = $_SESSION['user']['wallet_address'];

    try {
        // Проверяем, существует ли пользователь в базе данных
        $stmt_check = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE user_id = ? AND wallet_address = ?");
        $stmt_check->execute([$userId, $walletAddress]);

        if ($stmt_check->rowCount() > 0) {
            // Пользователь существует, выводим данные
            ?>

            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
            <head>
              <meta charset="UTF-8">
              <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/auth_styles.css">
              <title>CYPAY (CYP) MiniApp</title>
              <script src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-web-app.js"></script>
              <script src="https://unpkg.com/@tonconnect/ui@latest/dist/tonconnect-ui.min.js"></script>
            </head>
            <body>

            <div class="header">
                    <h1>CYPAY</h1>

                    <div class="settings">
                        <div><img src="assets/img/road-map-two-icon.svg" height="35px" alt=""></div>
                        <div><img src="assets/img/settings-icon.svg" height="40px" alt=""></div>
                        <div id="connect-wallet"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <div class="game">
              <header class="game__header">
                <p style="display: flex;justify-content: center;align-items: center;">
                  <h2 class="game__score">CYPAY LOGIN</h2>
                </p>
              </header>
              <div class="game__clicker-circle">
                <img class="game__main-image" src="assets/img/CYP.png" alt="main-image">
              </div>
              <div class="game__footer">
                  <div class="energy">
                    <p>Connect wallet login</p>
                  </div>
                <div class="settings">

                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
            <script src="navbar-loader.js"></script>
            <script src="main.js"></script>
            </body>
            </html>

            <?php
        } else {
            // Пользователь не найден, удаляем данные сессии
            session_unset(); // Удаляем все переменные сессии
            session_destroy(); // Уничтожаем сессию

            // Перенаправляем на auth.php с информацией о причине редиректа
            $_SESSION['error'] = 'User not found in the database or wallet address mismatch';
            header('Location: ./auth.php');
            exit();
        }
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        // Ошибка выполнения SQL-запроса
        error_log($e->getMessage()); // Логируем ошибку
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        $_SESSION['error'] = 'Database error occurred';
        header('Location: ./auth.php');
        exit();
    }

} else {
    // Сессия не установлена, перенаправляем на auth.php
    $_SESSION['error'] = 'Session not set';
    header('Location: ./auth.php');
    exit();
}
?>

auth_post.php
   <?php
session_start(); // Инициализация сессии

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
header('Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT'); // Истёкший заголовок
header('Pragma: no-cache'); // Для старых браузеров


require_once 'config.php'; // Подключение к базе данных
header('Content-Type: application/json'); // Заголовок ответа

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $data = json_decode($inputJSON, true);

    if (json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE && isset($data['user'])) {
        $user = $data['user'];
        $referrer_id = $data['referrer_id'] ?? null;
        $ref_url = $data['ref_url'] ?? null;
        $auth_date = $data['auth_date'] ?? null;
        $hash = $data['hash'] ?? null;
        $wallet_address = $data['wallet_address'] ?? null;

        try {
            // Проверяем, существует ли пользователь
            $stmt_check_user = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = ?");
            $stmt_check_user->execute([$user['id']]);
            $existing_user = $stmt_check_user->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            if ($existing_user) {
                // Пользователь существует - авторизация
                $_SESSION['user'] = [
                    'id' => $existing_user['user_id'],
                    'language_code' => $existing_user['language_code'],
                    'wallet_address' => $existing_user['wallet_address']
                ];

                // Перенаправляем на index.php
                header('Location: ./index.php');
                exit();
            } else {
                // Пользователя нет - регистрация
                $pdo->beginTransaction();

                $stmt_insert_user = $pdo->prepare("
                    INSERT INTO users (user_id, first_name, last_name, username, language_code, ref_url, auth_date, hash, wallet_address)
                    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
                ");
                $stmt_insert_user->execute([
                    $user['id'],
                    $user['first_name'],
                    $user['last_name'],
                    $user['username'],
                    $user['language_code'],
                    $ref_url,
                    $auth_date,
                    $hash,
                    $wallet_address
                ]);

                if ($referrer_id) {
                    $stmt_insert_referral = $pdo->prepare("
                        INSERT INTO referral (referrer_id, user_id)
                        VALUES (?, ?)
                    ");
                    $stmt_insert_referral->execute([$referrer_id, $user['id']]);
                }

                $pdo->commit();

                // Создаём сессию для нового пользователя
                $_SESSION['user'] = [
                    'id' => $user['id'],
                    'language_code' => $user['language_code'],
                    'wallet_address' => $wallet_address
                ];

                // Перенаправляем на index.php
                header('Location: ./index.php');
                exit();
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $pdo->rollBack();
            http_response_code(500);
            echo json_encode(['success' => false, 'message' => $e->getMessage()]);
        }
    } else {
        // Неверные данные
        http_response_code(400);
        echo json_encode(['success' => false, 'message' => 'Invalid JSON data']);
    }
} else {
    // Неверный метод запроса
    http_response_code(405);
    echo json_encode(['success' => false, 'message' => 'Method not allowed']);
}

?>

main.js
    async function init() {
    const tonConnectUI = new TON_CONNECT_UI.TonConnectUI({
        manifestUrl: 'tonconnect-manifest.json',
        buttonRootId: 'connect-wallet'
    });

    // Проверка доступности Telegram WebApp API
    if (!window.Telegram || !window.Telegram.WebApp) {
        console.error('Telegram WebApp API недоступен.');
        return;
    }

    const tg = window.Telegram.WebApp;
    const userInfo = tg.initDataUnsafe.user;

    // Функция для получения значения параметра
    function getQueryParam(param) {
        const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        return urlParams.get(param);
    }

    // Извлекаем значение параметра tgWebAppStartParam для десктоп версии
    const startAppParamDesktop = getQueryParam('tgWebAppStartParam');

    // Извлекаем значение параметра tgWebAppStartParam для андроид версии
    const initData = Telegram.WebApp.initDataUnsafe;
    const startAppParamAndroid = initData.start_param;

    // Получаем реферера из параметра start
    const referrerId = startAppParamDesktop || startAppParamAndroid || null;  // Здесь должно быть значение параметра start
    console.log('Referrer ID:', referrerId);

    // Создаем реферальную ссылку
    const referralLink = `https://t.me/TestTgMini_bot/testcypay?startapp=${userInfo.id}`;
    console.log('Referral Link:', referralLink);

    // Подписка на изменения статуса подключения кошелька
    const unsubscribe = tonConnectUI.onStatusChange(async (walletAndwalletInfo) => {
    const currentAccount = walletAndwalletInfo?.account;
    const currentWalletInfo = walletAndwalletInfo?.walletInfo;
    const isConnected = tonConnectUI.connected;

        if (isConnected) {
            console.log("Текущий аккаунт:", currentAccount);

            // Формируем данные для отправки на сервер
            const usersData = {
                query_id: tg.initDataUnsafe.query_id,
                user: {
                    id: userInfo.id,
                    first_name: userInfo.first_name,
                    last_name: userInfo.last_name,
                    username: userInfo.username,
                    language_code: userInfo.language_code
                },
                referrer_id: referrerId,
                ref_url: referralLink,
                auth_date: tg.initDataUnsafe.auth_date,
                hash: tg.initDataUnsafe.hash,
                wallet_address: currentAccount.address
            };

            console.log('Generated User Data:', usersData);

            // Отправка данных на сервер
            await sendUserDataToDB(usersData);
        } else {
            // Запрос к серверу для очистки сессии
                fetch('./logout.php', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    }
                })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                    if (data.status === 'success') {
                        console.log('Сессия успешно завершена на сервере.');
                        // Перенаправление на auth.php
                        window.location.href = './auth.php';
                    } else {
                        console.error('Ошибка при завершении сессии на сервере.');
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Ошибка сети при запросе на logout.php:', error);
                });
        }
    });
}

// Функция для отправки данных на сервер
async function sendUserDataToDB(usersData) {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('./auth_post.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(usersData)
        });

               if (response.ok) {
                    console.log('User data successfully sent to the database');
                    window.location.href = './index.php'; // Перенаправление после успешной авторизации
                } else {
                    console.error('Failed to send user data to the database', await response.text());
                }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error while sending data to the server:', error);
    }
}

// Инициализация
init();


Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример
